# How preserve fontsize of 2 Richtextbox or equal sizes

Tags: vb.net, textbox, richtextbox, font-size

I have 2 richtextboxes, I increase the font size of both correctly at same time with a button with this code.
The problem is: when I zoom directly on touchscreen and/or I do accidentally 2-fingered zoom on the touchpad, over one of them, it zooms too, but then I can't get back equal values pressing the button, both textboxes get diferent font size.
Clicking the button continues to increase 1 point each text, but at different sizes, I must adjust manually, (doing zoom again in the same way at 2 fingers) to get back the nearest size in the moddified one.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
RichTextBox1.Font = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.Font.Size + 1,RichTextBox1.Font.Style)
RichTextBox2.Font = RichTextBox1.Font
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a bit of a guess but try creating two new `Font` objects instead of creating one that you use in two places.

Comment: Also, you should dispose the existing `Font` objects if you're not going to use them any more.

Comment: Like this?:

 `RichTextBox1.Font.Dispose()
        RichTextBox2.Font.Dispose()
        RichTextBox1.Font = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.Font.Size + 1, RichTextBox1.Font.Style)
        RichTextBox2.Font = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, RichTextBox1.Font.Size + 1, RichTextBox1.Font.Style)`

I try, but doesnt work, still each one with his own size

Comment: Not like that. The order is wrong and you're using the wrong source to create the second `Font`. I'll post an answer so that I can post the code clearly, even though I suspect that it won't work anyway.

Comment: Are you talking about Font SIze, the `ZoomFactor` Property of the RichTextBox or Gesture Zoom? These are all different environment settings. If you want to synchronize the aspect of two Controls, you need to synchronize all factors.

Comment: i try too, but no work each one have different size

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will work but, as per my suggestion, try creating two new `Font` objects from the same source and disposing the old ones when you're completely done with them.

```vb
'We have no need of the second Font any more.
RichTextBox2.Font.Dispose()

'Get the first Font to use as a source.
Dim font1 = RichTextBox1.Font

'Create two new Fonts and assign them.
RichTextBox1.Font = New Font(font1.FontFamily, font1.Size + 1, font1.Style)
RichTextBox2.Font = New Font(font1.FontFamily, font1.Size + 1, font1.Style)

'We have no need of the first Font any more.
font1.Dispose()
```

Comment: still working in the same way...  two fingers in touchpad or opening 2 fingers touchscreen over one of them and it goes crazy: eachone take his own size no way to synchronize in the same font size. 
seems when you zoom in touchpad it magnifies in other unknow way, that its not controlled just by the font size... 
I read above about  `Zoomfactor` ignored property, suggested by @Jimi, then i try set it back at 1, without luck:
        `RichTextBox1.ZoomFactor = 1`